# Convert pandas dataframe into dictionary with keys one column and values the other

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Assuming I have a pandas DF as follows:

```
mydf=pd.DataFrame([{'sectionId':'f0910b98','xml':'<p/p>'},{'sectionId':'f0345b98','xml':'<a/a>'}])
mydf.set_index('sectionId', inplace=True)
```

[image]

I would like to get a dicctionary out of it as follwos:

```
{'f0910b98':'<p/p>', 'f0345b98':'<a/a>'}
```

I tried the following:

```
mydf.to_dict()
mydf.to_dict('records')
```

And it is not what I am looking for.

I am looking for the correct way to use to_dict()

Note: I know I can get the two columns into two lists and pack them in a dict like in:

```
mydict = dict(zip(mydf.sectionId, mydf.xml))
```

but I am looking for a pandas straight direct method (if there is one)

Comment: I would have gone with `dict(zip)` too...

Comment: None of the ```orient``` options do what you want to accomplish with your data in its current form. The dict(zip( approach is commonly used to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transpose your dataframe and then `to_dict` it and select the first item (the `xml` now-index).

```
mydf.T.to_dict(orient='records')[0]
```

returns

```
{'f0910b98': '<p/p>', 'f0345b98': '<a/a>'}
```